# how to add logical negation rules in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab

We need to support such piplines in gitlab:
when changes are commit in /sdk/*, sdk-pipline will run;
when other changes commit except for /sdk/*, main-pipline will run;

SDK pipline script is written as below:

```
run_sdk_build_pipeline:
stage: trigger
trigger:
    strategy: depend
    include: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.gitlab-ci/pipelines/sdk.gitlab-ci.yml"
rules:
    - changes:
        - sdk/**/*
```

Main pipline script is written as below:

```
run_main_pipeline:
stage: trigger
trigger:
    strategy: depend
    include: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.gitlab-ci/pipelines/main.gitlab-ci.yml"
rules:
    - changes:
        - // want to trigger it when changes commit except for /sdk/*
```

How to write this rule condition?
Expect to get help!

Answer (score 0):

In your case, [only:changes / except:changes examples](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#onlychanges--exceptchanges-examples) may help

```
run_sdk_build_pipeline:
stage: trigger
trigger:
    strategy: depend
    include: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/.gitlab-ci/pipelines/sdk.gitlab-ci.yml"
except:
    changes:
        - sdk/**/*
```